# the probability of X being even in a Poisson is higher than the probability of it being odd

Tags: probability, convergence-divergence, summation, random-variables, poisson-distribution

Ive came across this question and im not sure how to solve it :
if X~Pois($\lambda$)   , $\lambda >0$
with the identity

$$e^{\lambda}=\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{\lambda^k}{k!}, \space \forall \lambda \in \Bbb R$$

Prove that the probability of X being even is higher than the probability of it being odd

Comment: PS: $\displaystyle e^x = \sum\limits_{k=0}^\infty \dfrac{x^k}{k!}$ , or $\displaystyle e^\lambda = \sum\limits_{k=0}^\infty \dfrac{\lambda^k}{k!}$ .. Don't jumble them together

Comment: @grahamKemp I think I got it I have to add up $e^x$ and $e^{-x}$ in order to get an even sequence. After that, I'm not sure why I have to divide it by 2. And thank you !

Answer (score 2):

**1)** The sum of even X and odd X is equal to $1$.

**2)** The difference of even X and odd X is

$\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} (-1)^{k}\cdot e^{-\lambda}\cdot  \frac{\lambda^k}{k!}= e^{-\lambda}\cdot \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} (-1)^{k} \frac{\lambda^k}{k!}=e^{-2\lambda}$

Now you can sum 1) and 2). I think you can take it from here.

Answer (score 1):

You begin with the expressions:
$$\mathsf P(E) = \sum_{k=0}^\infty \mathsf P(X=2k) $$

$$\mathsf P(O) = \sum_{k=0}^\infty \mathsf P(X=2k+1)$$

Then you apply the p.m.f. , $\mathsf P(X=n)= \lambda^n e^{-\lambda}/n!$

Finally: Carefully subtract one from the other and examine the result.

Comment: you know how I try substracting but I have some trouble 
Here goes:
 $e^{-\lambda} (\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{\lambda^{2k}}{(2k)!} - \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{\lambda^{2k+1}}{(2k+1)!})$ 

to 

 $e^{-\lambda} (\frac{e^\lambda}{2\lambda^{\frac{1}{2}}} - \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{\lambda^{2k+1}}{(2k+1)!})$

I dont know how to do the second part